# <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"> not working

Tags: google-chrome, tags, format, meta

The below meta tag for format detection is not working in Chrome:

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

The mobile hyperlink allowed to be clicked and make a phone call in Chrome for the following code:

```
<a href="tel:+18002237440" id="sk_ftrCallTxt" class="sk_footerSubTitle">Call</a>
```

Comment: I'm speculating here, but my best guess (perhaps someone can confirm?) is that `telephone=no` will stop browsers from parsing long numbers in HTML and turning them, dynamically, into `tel:` links. But that won't affect the `tel:` links that are already hardcoded into the document.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might because you forgot to 'close'

It should be this:

`<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />`

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` is meant to prevent iOS (Chrome ignores this header AFAIK) to convert normal text such as:

```html
<p>This is a normal text with a phone number: +1 202-918-2132</p>
```

into links automatically.

If you explicitly create an anchor with a `tel:` schema, then it keeps behaving the same, as in your example.